# Querying PDF's using command line?

Tags: pdf, command-line

Recently I came across command line to find damaged JPEG here at http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/2352/find-corrupted-jpeg-image-files.

If there are some commands related to PDF I will be happy? often I play with PDF for many reasons.

Finding number of words? Finding Number of Lines? Finding Number of Pages?

Is is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I often use [pdfinfo](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_pdfinfo.htm)

There is also [pdffonts](http://linuxcommand.gds.tuwien.ac.at/man_pages/pdffonts1.html) to display the fonts used in the pdf file.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few command-line PDF tools that may be of use to you:

- http://www.coherentpdf.com/
- http://www.pdf-tools.com/asp/products.asp?name=CLE
- http://www.accesspdf.com/pdftk/